# How do I solve this differential equation (involving Fourier series)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

$$x(t) = 4y''(t)+4y'(t)+17y(t)$$

where,

$$x(t) = \sum^\infty_{k=1}\left((-1)^{k}\left(-\frac{2\cdot}{k}\right)\sin kt\right) = \sum^\infty_{k=-\infty}\frac{j(-1)^k}{k}e^{jkt},\quad k\not=0$$

and,

$$y(t) = \sum^\infty_{k=-\infty}c_ke^{jk\omega_0t}$$

- $x(t)$ is an input signal, and $y(t)$ is an output signal.
- Objective: *Find an expression for $c_k$*

---

Without preparing anything about differential equations in my textbook about transformations, this appears. I assume it's possible to figure this out, but I'm stuck after trying for more than 2 hours.

Does the fact that $x(t)$ is an input signal and that $y(t)$ is an output signal even matter in finding an expression for $c_k$?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: what is the derivative (and the second derivative) of y (t)? If you got that, just plug everything together with the formula for x (t) into the big formula. Now, use the fact that the complex exponentials are independent to get rid of the sums. Finally, you can solve for each $c_k$ individually...

The note with x being input and y being output doesn't change anything. You could change the roles or declare both to be outputs, does change nothing...

Comment: So, from what I understand, $\omega_0 = 1$, as per $x(t)$. Following this I get that $x(t) = \sum^\infty_{k=-\infty}c_k e^{i\,k\,t}\left(-4k^2+4jk+17\right)$. Substituting the definition for $x(t)$ in **LHS** has what implications now? That I can cross out the exponentials and the summation?

Comment: $\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac {j (-1)^k}{k} e^{jkt}=\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}(-4k^2+4jk+17) c_ke^{jkt} $. Now, collect all terms belonging to the same exponential  and set them to zero:$\frac {j (-1)^k}{k}=(-4k^2+4jk+17) c_k$. Now, solve for $ c_k $.